# Sum columns in Power BI matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am working on a matrix in Power BI and I am not figuring out how to sum each column recursively until the total:

[image: My table]

And this should be the resulting matrix (as an example, rows):

[image: My result]

Some clarifications:

- The months (columns) are dynamically generated based on the transaction month. I could filter the data to get the same data for only three months.
- "Nombre proveedor" stands for "Vendor name".
- I don't care about "Total" row.

These are my values:

[image: My values]

So, I think I should create a measure with DAX to replace "**Accounting Balance**" to sum the previous column (month) or show nothing (to avoid zeroes).

Searching on internet I found several sites to get the running totals by rows, but not by columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this:

```
Maesure =
CALCULATE (
    [Accounting Balance],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'table' ),
        'table'[Transaction month] <= MAX ( 'table'[Transaction month] )
    )
)
```

Comment: This is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/XOBlhjF.png
All the rows have the same values.

Comment: I don't think I can help you further without a sample of your data.

Comment: I am displaying "the sample" of my data which is actually real and that's why I have hidden the vendors names. I have used  "Vendor 1", "Vendor" and "Vendor 3" as an example in the second image. What else do you need?

Comment: Your sample looks like a pivottable. What a table of sampledata, that i can copy to PowerBI and work with.

Comment: I just solved it by creating two tables for months and vendors. ty anyway